# Why is death metal being played in the interrogation room in Homeland: Blind Spot

Tags: plot-explanation, homeland

In [Homeland: Blind Spot](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2023998/), after Afzal Hamid (I think) is interrogated by Saul Berenson and left alone in the room to reveal details of the Terrorist organization, why is there `silence` and `death metal music` time sliced in the interrogation room?
Does this happen in real interrogation situations too?

Comment: Yes, it happens; your government does that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because after an hour of being forced to listen to death metal you'll confess to anything.

They were practicing sleep deprivation, where just as he's about to nod off they jolt him awake again.

Comment: I'd have used Barry Manilow, myself. And I'd have tortured him at the Copa.. Copacabana.... pain and confession are always in session at the Copaaaaaaa.... Don't tell them anything...

Comment: Modern renditions of this torture use *Friday* as their song of choice.

Comment: Does this really work?

Comment: I don't know, I've never tried it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_deprivation#Interrogation

Comment: Your first sentence is simply wrong, because you present that as a universal truth. Seems like a joke answer to a highly uninformed question.

Answer (score 7):

It's a form of "not really torture" called Advanced Interrogation Techniques.
The band they used are called Gridlink, by the way.